# Implementation of horizontal scrollbars on Android?

Tags: android

How do I to implement horizontal scroll bars on Android? Are there some guidelines for it or some demo code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) in Android.